# Python Ouath2 PKCE

Tags: python-3.x, pkce

So I have started the process of transferring a complete web application (php, JavaScript and html) to a client based python application. Normally when you get a callback URL you handle that in php or even javascript. I'm very unsure of how to handle it in python. I have seen different documentation of how to implement Ouath2 Pkce and normal Ouath2 but what confuses me is how do i get a callback like this (https://localhost/callback/?code=balsh12312312&state=unique-state) how can I get the code and check the unique-state? Do I need to use a web app like Flask or is their another solution out there ?